# How can I display the status of my cameras in a Grafana dashboard?

Tags: python, camera, grafana, iot, dashboard

Basically I'm trying to do is to fetch the state of the cameras connected to an NVD to be displayed to a Grafana dashboard. I got the NVD's API and in it there is a way to see the state of the connected cameras, what I managed to do so far is to show the number of cameras and their status in text like this:

```
Camera[0] = false
Camera[1] = false
Camera[2] = false
Camera[3] = false
Camera[4] = true
Camera[5] = false
Camera[6] = false
Camera[7] = false
```

I just wanted to know how I can display or store this information in a dashboard.
And i'm using Python to do this

**Sorry for any kind of spelling mistake, english is not my first language**

This is the code i'm using to fetch these information

```
import time
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth

url = 'http://192.168.1.10/XXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX'
username = 'XXX'
password = 'XXX'

while True:
    response = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth(username, password))
    data = response.text.split('\n')
    camera_info = {}
    for line in data:
        if line.startswith('camera') and 'DeviceInfo.Enable=' in line:
            camera_number = line.split('[')[1].split(']')[0]
            enable_info = line.split('=')[1]
            camera_info[camera_number] = enable_info

    for i in range(0, 8):
        enable_status = camera_info.get(str(i), 'Not Found')
        print(f"Camera[{i}] = {enable_status}")
    time.sleep(5)
    print('\n')
```